# Angular form submiting twice

Tags: angularjs

I have a form, it sends data to a database, but it makes it twice.

Here is the code of controller and example of html view.

```js
        $scope.addEvent = function(type) {
            if (!$scope.sentAdd) {
            $scope.newEvent.admission = type;
            $scope.newEvent.customer_id = $scope.curUID;
            console.log($scope.newEvent);
            $http({
              url: '/addEvent',
              method: "POST",
              data: $.param($scope.newEvent),
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
              }
            })
            .success(function(data){
                    //console.log(data);
                    $scope.newEvent = $scope.cleanEvent;
                    $scope.addEventForm.$setPristine();
                    $scope.sentType = type;
                    $scope.sentAdd = true;
                    $.fancybox.close();
                    $.fancybox.open({ href: '#eventSuccess', type: 'inline' });
            });
            } 
        };
```

```html
<form name="addEventForm" novalidate>
  <input type="text" ng-model="text">
  <a ng-click="addEvent('Paid')">Add Paid Event</a><br>
  <a ng-click="addEvent('Free')">Add Free Event</a>
</form>
```

Comment: What does *twice* mean? Does it print the result twice or really POST twice?

Comment: As @Anson says, check your Network tab and verify whether two separate requests are actually being made. If not, the problem is in your backend not your Angular code. Nothing in the provided code would cause two submissions.

Comment: most commons issues about that is, user clicking twice, duplicate declaration of controller, or module, ng-submit and ng-click using together, or sometimes dirty checking issue but that normally wont happen with ng-click.

Comment: Maybe fancybox cause the problem?
The form opened in fancybox

Comment: Do multiple requests get made? Can't determine problem without isolating it

Comment: I call console.log() on send, and it calls twice.
I use image uploader from fancybox, and it is also called twice

Comment: @user1679210 is `$scope.addEvent` called anywhere else? Any events/watchers? Unlikely I know but checking, the button isn't being double clicked is it? Because if you clicked that button n times, n requests would be made.

Comment: #scope.addEvent does not called anywhere else, it is only one function to send a form. Button clicked once.

Comment: I use also slick-carousel and within it I specify own fancybox for each carousel-image.
When I cut this part of code - all works fine. How I need to specify fancybox for slick to be friendly with addEvent fancybox?